# overloading of template function error C2688

Tags: c++, templates

i can't compile the following code

```
namespace sequential_sort
{
template<class T>
void sort(std::list<T>& source)
{
    sort(source.begin(), source.end()); //(1)
}
template<class Iter>
void sort(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    if(begin == end)
         return;
    typedef Iter::value_type value_type;
    value_type value = *(begin);
    Iter part = std::partition(begin, end, [&value](const    value_type&->bool{return   t < value;});
    sort(begin, part);
    Iter divide = part;
    divide++;
    sort(divide, end); 
}
}
```

It says that at line (1) I have error C2688 ambiguous call to overloaded functions.
I can't understand why, overloaded functions even have different number of parameters?

Comment: Could you name your function something other than `sort`? There is `std::sort`, and argument dependent lookup to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues at play:

1) You need to declare your single parameter `sequential_sort::sort` function *before* the two parameter one, unless you want to another `sort` function. You probably don't see the effect of this because you are using a Windows C++ compiler, which is not standards compliant in this respect. What should have happened is that `std::sort` was unambiguously picked, and that wouldn't compile because it requires random access iterators (`std::list` has a `sort` member function which you should use instead of `std::sort`).

2) Once that is fixed, since you are passing `std::list` iterators to the two parameter `sort`, [**argument dependent lookup**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (ADL) means `std::sort` is considered too. This is the cause of the ambiguity. You can fix this by being specific about which two-parameter `sort` you want to use:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

namespace sequential_sort
{

template<class Iter>
void sort(Iter begin, Iter end) { }

template<class T>
void sort(std::list<T>& source)
{
  sequential_sort::sort(source.begin(), source.end()); //(1)
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

}
```